# simple class inheritance in c++ compiler errors

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want my Dog class to properly inherit the functions in Pet so that the code in main will execute properly. The compiler warns that private methods are called from the base class Pet.

main:

```
Dog * d = new Dog( "Muffin" );

cout << "The " << d->getVariety( ) << " " << d->getName( ) << " speaks by saying " << d->speak( ) << endl;
```

classes:

```
class Pet
{
public:
Pet( );
Pet( std::string name, std::string variety, std::string says )
{

    myName=name;
    myVariety=variety;
    howIspeak=says;
}

std::string getName( ) const
{
    return myName;
};
public:
std::string getVariety( ) const
{
    return myVariety;
};

std::string speak() const
{

    return howIspeak;
};

protected:
std::string myName;
std::string myVariety;
std::string howIspeak;
};

class Dog: Pet
{
public:
Dog( );
Dog( std::string name );

virtual void speak( );
};
```

Comment: `speak` needs to be virtual in `class Pet`.  Also, I think you mean `class Dog : public Pet`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ defaults to private inheritance. Hence use

```
class Dog: public Pet
```

Answer (score 1):

class has private inheritance by default

```
 class Dog: public Pet
```